# Android: Is it possible to customize a common intent's theme?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app where I need the user to pick a file. As my whole app has a dark theme applied, I wonder if I can get a similar look for the file chooser intent. (Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)

I currently do as follows:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```